# Combining Scala Parser Combinators From Different Objects

Tags: regex, scala, parsing, parser-combinators

This is a very similar question to [Scala: How to combine parser combinators from different objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2650254/scala-how-to-combine-parser-combinators-from-different-objects), but it is different in that the solution proposed there does not work for my use case.

I have been unable to find a solution given the somewhat sparse documentation for Scala Parser Combinators, but I am also new to Scala so it may be that I am missing something.

Problem statement: I am trying to combine two regex parser combinators that handle whitespace very differently. As per the solution for the question above, I have put the parser I want to combine into a `trait` for my class to use. The issue is that one parser combinator overrides the `skipWhitespace` member of `RegexParsers`, and the other does not:

```
// This parser handles whitespace in a very particular way
trait WhiteSpaceParser extends RegexParsers {
    override def skipWhitespace = false
    def myWhiteSpaceParser: Parser[Any] = // <special whitespace CFG implementation>
}

// This parser does not care about whitespace, except where myWhiteSpaceParser is used
class DocumentParser extends RegexParsers with WhiteSpaceParser
{
    // This parser must skip whitespace, i.e., skipWhitespace = true

    def myDocumentParser: Parser[Any] = // <implementation that uses myWhiteSpaceParser>
}
```

Question: How can I utilize `myWhiteSpaceParser`, where whitespace is handled in a very particular way, from within `DocumentParser`, where whitespace should be ignored (aside from this exception)? One solution is to handle whitespace everywhere, but requires a lot of changes throughout `DocumentParser` and is more error prone. I am hoping that there is another way.

Thanks!

Comment: this might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10810172/scala-parser-that-sometimes-skips-whitespace-and-sometimes-does-not

Comment: There are some other _Scala_ parsers that you might want to consider. [Parboiled2](https://github.com/sirthias/parboiled2) is very fast (much faster than _Scala Parser Combinator_), and IMHO handles _whitespace_ in a more intuitive manner. I know it can handle the case you're looking to address. I'm less familiar with [FastParse](http://www.lihaoyi.com/fastparse/), but that might work for you too...